# SQL Hive - Calculate the rolling SUM,AVG for previous months

Tags: sql, oracle, hadoop, hive, bigdata

I need to calculate the sum of amt for the past 6 and 12 months for the ID & Dt
tried using over partition by and case statements but not getting the expected o/p.

```
Id             dt            amt
11112222222    2018-03-01    100
11112222222    2018-03-01    100
**11112222222    2017-03-01    100**
11112222222    2017-09-01    100
11112222222    2017-03-01    300
11112222222    2018-01-01    100
11112222222    2018-05-01    200
**11112222222    2016-03-01    450**
11112222222    2018-04-01    500
```

O/P:

```
Id               Dt       Sum6mon    Avg6mon    Sum12mon    Avg12months
11112222222    2018-03-01    400     150        1500           187.5
11112222222    2017-03-01    100     100        550             275 
etc...
```

date format - YYYY-MM-DD

Answer (score 2):

> tried using over partition by

Yes, for things like rolling sum/average analytic functions are recommended. I think the best is to use `range` windowing clause instead of `case when`:

```
select id, dt, amt,
       sum(amt) over (partition by id order by dt range interval '6'  month preceding) s06,
       avg(amt) over (partition by id order by dt range interval '6'  month preceding) a06,
       sum(amt) over (partition by id order by dt range interval '12' month preceding) s12,
       avg(amt) over (partition by id order by dt range interval '12' month preceding) a12
  from t order by dt
```

**<sup>[SqlFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/83b2cd/975)</sup>**

If you provide sample data please also attach **matching** expected output. And in this case it's impossible that sum for day `2018-03-01` was 1500, all previous rows gives 1250. 
Matching output allows us verify our results and react :) Also it's helpful to show your code and efforts.

Answer (score 1):

In case if you need the `amt` sum and average per every distinct `{ID, date}` pair,  you may try the following query:

```
   SELECT
   Id,
   dt,
   SUM(CASE WHEN dt >= from_unixtime(unix_timestamp() - 3600 * 24 * 30 * 6, 'yyyy-MM-dd') THEN amt ELSE 0 END) as Sum6mon,  
   SUM(amt) as Sum12mon,
   AVG(CASE WHEN dt >= from_unixtime(unix_timestamp() - 3600 * 24 * 30 * 6, 'yyyy-MM-dd') THEN amt ELSE 0 END) as Avg6mon,  
   AVG(amt) as Avg12mon          
   FROM  
   <your table name>
   WHERE   
   dt BETWEEN from_unixtime(unix_timestamp() - 3600 * 24 * 30 * 12, 'yyyy-MM-dd') AND from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(), 'yyyy-MM-dd')  
   GROUP BY Id,dt  
   ;
```

But you have to keep in mind that the combination `from_unixtime(unix_timestamp())` is quite slow, so try to replace it with static dates whenever possible